# Como ignorar archivos ejecutables

Tags: git, github, gcc

Tengo una carpeta con muchos ejercicios en el lenguaje de C, utilicé el compilador gcc para crear los ejecutables.
Quiero subir la carpeta de ejercicios a un repositorio en github, hay alguna manera de ignorar los archivos que creo gcc?

en mi .gitignore intente con
*.exe
*.out
*.app

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Tal vez te interese revisar algunas sugerencias como estas https://stackoverflow.com/q/8237645/13419694

Comment: bastante útiles, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hola cuando usas git suele crear un archivo directorio raíz llamado ".gitignore" ahí adentro le podes poner las extensiones que quieras ignorar.
Por ejemplo:

```
*.exe
*.gcc
```

Asegúrate de que el archivo .gitignore esté en el directorio raíz de tu repositorio y que lo incluyas en tu próximo commit para que surta efecto en el repositorio.

Saludos

Comment: buenas, eso intenté, pero los ejecutables creados por gcc no tienen ninguna extensión, no se si es porque estoy en linux

Comment: y entonces ahi le vas a tener que poner el nombre del ejecutable. por ejemplo:  ``` ejercicio1
ejercicio2```